# number_format() to eliminate .06

Tags: php, regex, numbers, format

I am having trouble of eliminating .06 using number_format()

what I want to do is:

56.00 => 56

56.10 => 56.10

56.06 => 56

I did it with regex but I can't eliminate it, maybe my statement is wrong.

```
$num = 50.06;
$num = preg_replace("/\.0*$/",'',$num);
```

I need your help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it correct that you're putting the number first into `$num` and then trying to substitute it on `$x`?

Comment: Could you explain the logic? Why does it keep the fraction when it's `.10`, but not when it's `.06`?

Comment: hi, sorry. It's $num, not $x. my bad. already edited the question.

Comment: @Barmar sometime the result of a division is for example 56.06, I want to make or round it off to 56, but not the 56.10 or 56.75 or 20.18.

Comment: What about `56.04` or `56.07`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex:

```
/\.0[0-9]+/
```

Working [**DEMO**](https://3v4l.org/Icj19).

So:

```
$num1 = 50.06;
$num1 = preg_replace("/\.0[0-9]+/",'',$num1); //50

$num2 = 50.10;
$num2 = preg_replace("/\.0[0-9]+/",'',$num2); //50.1
```

Reference:

- [preg_replace()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Answer (score 1):

The correct regex is  `\.0[0-9]{1}$`

The last param of preg_replace is $num

Comment: I have forgotten the \

Answer (score 1):

This may be stupid as I'm tired and ready to head out, but:

```
if(($num - intval($num)) > .1) {
    $num = number_format($num, 2);
} else {
    $num = number_format($num, 0);
}
```

Comment: This won't do the desired thing for `56.06`.

Comment: @Barmar: Whoa, wait, what?  I just saw that.

Comment: Almost there, change it to `>=`. Although this might not work due to roundoff errors.

Answer (score -3):

`$num = 56.06;
echo $num = number_format($num, 0);`

Comment: If the $num is '56.10' ?